# Copy an existing Azure Repo Files to another Azure Repo

Tags: azure, repository, .net-6.0, file-transfer, .net-4.8

I'm gearing up to upgrade from dotnet 4.8 to dotnet 6. I create a new azure repo, so I need to get all the folders/files from the source repo into the newly created repo. Is there a way to quickly transfer files? I looked around but I'm seeing just TFS to azure repo or local to azure repo.

Comment: do you need to preserve git history? Why not just copy the files and create a commit?

Comment: No, I don’t need the git history. You mean copy the files in vs or azure DevOps. I’m not sure i understand

Answer (score 0):

1. Clone the  Net4.8 repo onto your local drive
2. Clone the Net6 repo onto your local drive
3. On your local drive copy all the files except the .git folder from the Net4.8 folder to the Net6 folder
4. In the Net6 folder git add commit and push